# Why does this return an ssl error when using pybitcointools?

Tags: python, pybitcointools

[image: What could the source of this error be?]

Really confused as to why this error persists.
I have upgraded pip ( I believe)
And have installed pybitcointools...

Comment: Either the explorer you are using has an invalid/expired cert, or there is an openssl misconfiguration on your machine (or you're missing some ca certs)